# Ruby Docs Update Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have MacPorts installed Ruby on Rails which I am have been updating and reworking since yesterday as I want to get back into studying this language.

**Specs**

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i686-darwin10]
rails -v
Rails 3.0.3
gem -v
1.8.5
```

**The Journey**

So far it has been quite the journey to get Ruby, Rails and Gems to work on my Mac. On following a tutorial I decided to install/ update Rails API docs and I ran into these **errors**:

```
Password:
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.from_installed_gems called from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/commands/rdoc_command.rb:58.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.installed_spec_directories is deprecated, use Specification.dirs. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.installed_spec_directories called from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:47.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex.from_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-10-01.
Gem::SourceIndex.from_gems_in called from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:47.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#initialize is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#initialize called from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:67.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#spec_dirs= is deprecated, use Specification.dirs=. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#spec_dirs= called from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:94.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#refresh! called from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:95.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in is deprecated with no replacement. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#load_gems_in called from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:320.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec called from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/source_index.rb:127.
NOTE: Gem::SourceIndex#add_spec is deprecated, use Specification.add_spec. It will be removed on or after 2011-11-01.
Gem::SourceIndex#each called from /opt/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/commands/rdoc_command.rb:58.
Installing ri documentation for activesupport-3.2.3...

unrecognized option `--encoding'

For help on options, try 'rdoc --help'

ERROR:  While generating documentation for activesupport-3.2.3
... MESSAGE:   exit
... RDOC args: --ri --op /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/doc/activesupport-3.2.3/ri --encoding UTF-8 lib --title activesupport-3.2.3 Documentation --quiet
```

when I did `gem server` the server was started up. So I probably installed docs a year ago and totally forgot about it.

What can I do to get rid of all these errors? Or can I safely ignore them and keep on going?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can safely ignore those errors.

For now you can install gems by specifying `gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc` to install Rails without those errors.

And in the future, you could add:

```
gem: --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

to your `~/.gemrc` file, to globally ignore documentation for future gem installs.

Also, if you're just getting started I would recommend using a ruby version manager such as [rvm](https://rvm.io) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). It makes life so much easier when managing different ruby versions and gemsets.

Comment: Thanks for the input @Mark Sands ! You are the second guy recommending RVM. Going to look into it. Also realized the book RailsSpace I bought quite some time ago has a lot of code that is outdated.

Comment: Not a problem! Be sure to read the pros and cons of rvm and rbenv to formulate your own opinion on which version manager to use.

Answer (score 5):

Try `gem install rdoc` or  `gem update rdoc` if you have rdoc version < 3.0.

RDoc generates Documentation from Ruby Source Files. So, as @Mark Sands says, it's not absolutely necessary to make your code run it can be nice to have and addresses the root of your errors.

Answer (score 3):

I get the same warnings here on `Debian` linux and I am using `rvm` with `ruby-1.9.3-p194`.

I eliminated most of them by changing line 127 of

```
~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/source_index.rb
```

`127 add_spec gemspec if gemspec` to `127 Gem::Specification.add_spec gemspec if gemspec`

As for the others they say deprecated with no replacement.

I only found this thread because I am trying to find out more about these.
Does anyone suppose there is an update?
The warnings state that these will be removed on or after `2011-11-01`.
The time has come and gone now.